# How to create a counting generator/iterator cascade in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, generator, yield

Newer versions of **JavaScript** allow to use [generators/iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/The_Iterator_protocol) in combination with the `yield` keyword.

---

**Background of my question**

Consider the following generator, which "produces" numbers (digits) from 0 to 9:

```
// generator (produces numbers from 0 to 9, then stops)
function *zcounter() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i<=9) {
    yield i;
    i++;
  }
}
```

Now I want to use it to **replace** the following function, which uses 3 nested `for` loops:

```
// e.g.: var iArray=[0,0,0];
function IterateCascade1(iArray) {
    var iterations=0;
    for (var x=0; x<=9; x++) {
        iArray[0]=x;
        for (var y=0; y<=9; y++) {
            iArray[1]=y;
            for (var z=0; z<=9; z++) {
                iArray[2]=z;
                logArray(iArray);
                iterations++;
            }
        }
    }
    return iterations;
}
```

---

**The problem**

If you invoke the function above like

```
console.log("Iterations: "+IterateCascade1([0,0,0]));
```

Then it will count 1000 times from 000 to 999, which is exactly doing what I want.

The disadvantage is, that can only use arrays with 3 elements, you can't pass arrays with more elements.

---

To solve it by using the generator `zcounter()`, I tried the following:

```
// e.g.: var iArray=[0,0,0];
function IterateCascade2(iArray) {
    var iterations=0;
    // generate 3 iterators
    var gArray = [];
    for(var i=0; i<iArray.length; i++) {    
        var g=zcounter();
        gArray[i]=g;
    }
    // loop through
    for(var a in gArray) {
        //console.log("a:"+a);
        var g=gArray[a];
        var gnext=g.next();
        while (!gnext.done)
        {
            iArray[a]=gnext.value;
            logArray(iArray);
            gnext=g.next();
            iterations++;
        }
    }
    return iterations;
}
```

If you invoke the function above like

```
console.log("Iterations: "+IterateCascade2([0,0,0]));
```

Then it will count only 30 times, and it will not go through all 1000 numbers as `IterateCascade1` does it.

Furthermore, if you pass larger arrays like

```
console.log("Iterations: "+IterateCascade2([0,0,0,0]));
```

then it will "count" every digit from 0 to 9, but will not go through all 10000 combinations.

---

**Question**

I know that somehow there is a recursion missing.

- How can `IterateCascade2` be modified so it does the right thing (cycle through all combinations and you can pass integer arrays of any size)?

---

**Note:**

To display the combinations, I have used

```
function logArray(x) {
    var result="";
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) { result += x[i].toString(); }
    console.log(result);
}
```

in the examples above. You can use the developer tools of any of the 3 browsers or JSShell to run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with recursion

```
function iterareIndex(index, array, iterator) {
    var previousValue = array[index];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        array[index] = i;
        if (index == array.length - 1) {
            iterator(array);
        } else {
            iterareIndex(index + 1, array, iterator);
        }
    }
    array[index] = previousValue;
}

function IterateCascade2(array){
    iterareIndex(0, array, logArray);
}
```

---

By the way, this will give you the same output and is probably shorter:

```
var size = 3;
var prefix = '';
for(var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    prefix += '0';
}
for(var i = 0, l = Math.pow(10, 3); i < l; ++i){
    var printableValue = (prefix+i).slice(-size);
    console.log(printableValue);
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Actually, the example in my question is part of a bigger program which is why in my case the 1st solution you have given is what I need.